# Errors while invoking Web service using `Curl` command from Unix terminal

Tags: web-services, unix

I have trying to invoke a web service from my script using the `Curl` command . I got the script from [HERE.](http://en.newinstance.it/2008/11/11/calling-webservice-at-the-unix-command-line/)

**My Script :**

```
#! /bin/sh

ENDPOINT="http://mathertel.de/AJAXEngine/S01_AsyncSamples/CalcService.asmx"
VALUE=1234567890
if [ -n "${1}" ]; then
    VALUE=${1}
fi

curl --silent \\
     --data \\
     @- \\
     --header 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' \\
     --user-agent "" \\
     ${ENDPOINT} <<EOF | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <CalcPrimeFactors xmlns="http://www.mathertel.de/S01_AsyncSamples/">
      <inputText>${VALUE}</inputText>
    </CalcPrimeFactors>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
EOF
```

**And i get these Errors :**

```
./CalcService.sh: 10: ./CalcService.sh: --data: not found
./CalcService.sh: 11: ./CalcService.sh: @-: not found
./CalcService.sh: 12: ./CalcService.sh: --header: not found
./CalcService.sh: 13: ./CalcService.sh: --user-agent: not found
./CalcService.sh: 14: ./CalcService.sh: ./CalcService.sh: 14: ./CalcService.sh: http://mathertel.de/AJAXEngine/S01_AsyncSamples/CalcService.asmx: not found
 xmllint: not found
```

Now i have installed curl, and tried to install `xmllint` but it did not get installed, saying it's a broken package.

Anybody has any suggestions as to what is happening here and what i can do to mitigate this ? This is driving me crazy...

Comment: why are you using '\\', instead of '\' to continue your `curl` cmd line? Also make sure there are is not white space after the trailing '\' char AND if you have edited this script in Windows and then moved to Unix/linux, try running `dos2unix myScript`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : thanks , i will try this out and let you know...